# Results not returning

Tags: php, sql, return

This is random as anything, but the following query seems to be returning no results?? there is data the the table and the naming is correct and it works in a different part of the site. for some reason the array is staying blank where it should be me back 5 results.

Table name: gallery_album
Contain 1 column: Name
Entries 5

```
    include $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/includes/db.inc.php';
    {
        $sql = 'SELECT Name FROM gallery_albums';
        $s = $pdo->prepare($sql);
        $s->execute();
    }
        foreach ($s as $row)
        {
            $albumnames[] = array('Name' => $row['Name']);
        }
include $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/pages/albumli.html.php';
```

Comment: Did you declare `$albumnames` as array?

Comment: Yeah, but for some reason it's just started working and I haven't changed anything??? is it possible that there was an issue on the server to cause this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do a `fetchAll` like this:

```
<?php

include $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/includes/db.inc.php';
{
    $sql = 'SELECT Name FROM gallery_albums';
    $s   = $pdo->prepare($sql);
    $s->execute();
}
$rows = $s->fetchAll();
foreach($rows as $row){
    $albumnames[] = array('Name' => $row['Name']);
}
include $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/pages/albumli.html.php';
```

Answer (score 0):

I use mysqli not PDO but am curious at which point do you fetch your data ? Your foreach loop might not be assigning any data after execute. Try to var_dump($s) the results of the execute and see if you get any results.

Comment: The data is fetched as part of the initial page, this particular one is for a menu that will expand as the table has more data input. nothing fancy just creating a simple list for links

Comment: Not quite as my code starting working anyway so I'm not enntirely sure what happened but I appreciated the alternative suggestion (and I can mark this as answered myself because I'm a new member)